# Will there be an "invitation per SO question" feature for the chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, invitation

Most of the users I answer questions to are fairly new to the system.

That means they have a low reputation (often lower than 15) on SO.
You can guess their reputation on MSO... They usually don't know Meta.

Yet, they are the ones who would most benefit from a quick chat to clarify their questions and validate some possible solutions (like in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403827/hudson-and-ucm-clearcase))

Would you consider the (future) possibility to allow a legitimate chat user (more than 20 rep on MSO) to invite that new user to a specific room dedicated to the OP question?

In other words, that user would not be able to connect to the chat unless invited.
Once connected, he/she wouldn't be able to join other rooms/create other rooms (or even see those rooms for that matter).

**He/she would only be able to join/leave the specific room created by the legitimate chat user for the sole purpose of a "live support session" for a specific SO question.**

(the all process could be automated, allowing for each user *answering* a question to invite the OP to a specific chat session, in a room automatically created for said question, and which would be removed after a day or so of inactivity.
Those "rooms" would need a separate space in order to not pollute the usual "social" rooms)

The alternative right now would be to:

- ask them to create real quick an MSO account
- post two (intelligent) answers
- wait for me to upvote them (which is abusing the system)

Not exactly ideal.

Comment: Was this feature dropped with the merged chat?

Comment: Be nice if you could attach a chat conversation to a question.. otherwise all the good conversation would be lost.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82738/allow-temporary-guest-accounts-in-chat/113977#113977

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**:

Note that the technique described here no longer appears in the FAQ, and no longer seems to work.

**Pre-edit**:

The [current chat.stackoverflow FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq) mentions:

#### How can I discuss a particular question?

> If you want to discuss a certain question that has been posted on Stack Overflow, you can create a room for it.
>
> **To do so, just prepend "chat." to the question link**.
>
> For example, if you want to chat about [How big is an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940253) ("How big is an integer?"), visit https://chat.stackoverflow.com/questions/3940253.
> If there is an existing room for this question, you will enter it immediately.
> Otherwise, a new room will be created with you as the owner.

That looks like a good start, **but I am not sure if a new SO user (with less than 10 rep) will be able to join** a dedicated room that I will have created.
So the "invitation" feature might still be needed in that case.

Comment: I'm not seeing this feature anymore.  I also tried it, and it didn't work.  What's my alternative?  Spam comments until the link is auto-created (yes this isn't a real alternative)?

Comment: @Merlyn: agreed, this must be why the question has still a [meta-tag:status-planned] tag attached to it.

Comment: @Merlyn -- see my post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98926/create-comment-spawned-chatrooms-for-the-question-not-for-the-users which was shot down... (well at least at the moment it is)