# Practical method to answer contact requests in questions using SE-chat

Tags: discussion, chat

A few times I've been requested nicely by the OP to make some kind of contact outside the SE world to discuss an answer. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788344/function-that-returns-affinity-between-texts/4881687#4881687):  *"I would like to share and discuss my solution with you, can we talk privately (email,chat,msn,fb) ? this little comment space here hurts me rly"*

I've no objection to this kind of requests, but I'd like to restrict them to the SE realm.

SE-chat seems a good tool to do that, but proposing it, and arranging a meeting date/time requires a lot of (almost spamming) comments.

So: Can someone come up with practical method for doing this?

Comment: @Trufa I'm not requesting (and don't want to request) a "go to chat" feature!

Comment: There is a "create a room for two users" function. Does that cover what you are requesting?

Comment: @Pekka I'm aware of that, tnx. I'm referring  to the "setup" stage. How could you _arrange_ a meeting in the less cumbersome way.

Comment: @belisarius (deleted my comment to avoid confusion over your actual question) my bad! the thing is, IMO if this is made by design, I don't see any other way than the spammy comments (maybe you could agree with the users to delete them once the conversation was started) but that, I think, Is what you were trying to avoid!

Comment: @Trufa exactly. Moreover that started spinning in my mind since _we_ had to arrange to chat, and it took us 5 comments with both of us online simultaneously :O

Comment: @belisarius I guessed you were talking about that! It sure took it's fair share of off topic comments!

Comment: related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59716/will-there-be-an-invitation-per-so-question-feature-for-the-chat

Comment: FWIW, what you call "a 'go to chat' feature" existed briefly around the time chat was rolled out, but was disabled some time ago.

Comment: @Popular I remember that, and personally, I agree with the decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SE-chat seems a good tool to do that, but proposing it, and arranging a meeting date/time requires a lot of (almost spamming) comments.

Proposing it can merely be an invitation. However, that would only work if both users have been in the chat at least once. And of course, one still needs to be online at (about) the same time, but that time could be discussed in the chat as well?

[image: Chat invite in global Inbox]

Comment: I am not aware of the necessary condition for receiving that message. You mean "Online in chat" or just "Active on SE"

Comment: @belisarius For this invite to work, both the users should have visited chat atleast once,

Comment: Ah, I got busted here, not knowing that. Thanks, @Sathya!

Comment: welcome @Arjan I learnt this the hard way!

Answer (score 1):

If the OP more questions after attempting to implement a solution, then it seems like posting a new question is the best route.

I agree, comments are not the best place to carry-on this conversation. But chat isn't really any better because the explanations are lost and are only see by you and the OP.  It would be better to have the further explanation in an updated answer or a new question and answer because others can make use of it and possibly provide alternate solutions.

In the exception cases that a chat is truly the best route: I would suggest that you just leave a single comment that you have created a room and in the room you can communicate back and forth about when to meet there in case you are not there at the same time.

Comment: I disagree IMO if the Go to chat was made by design a simple link could make the conversation available for everyone.

Comment: @jzd +1, because your answer is correct 99% of the time. That is why I'm not asking for a "goto chat" feature. I'm just trying to come up with a way to _catch_ exceptions :)

Comment: @belisarius, what about providing your email, just to use to arrange an SO chat?  Or create a room and just leave a single comment with a time that you will be there.

Comment: @jzd That second option (creating a room and leaving only one  comment)  seems almost right. However there is the [`Two Generals' Problem`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) on the practical side

Comment: @belisarius, true.  However, I guess you can just leave a comment that you have created a room and in the room you can communicate back and forth about when to meet there in case you are not there at the same time.

Comment: @jzd Seems the way right now. Let's see if someone can devise something better.

Comment: A new question and an edit to the old one to link to the new one for related subject matter?