# Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat? Yes Please! Well you can't, so there?

Tags: bug, comments, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep)

This has happened to me twice this week and is annoying...

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

That's a good idea. Real-time chat would be a nice way of removing the ambiguity from the question and then we can answer it.

> <*username*> has only 15 reputation, not yet enough to chat
>
> (click on this box to dismiss)

Oh... right! Has StackOverflow only just computed this?

Can we have it fixed so that StackOverflow doesn't offer options that are not actually available?

Comment: How many people +1 the killer title without even reading the content? hmmm....

Comment: (will review - any new comments etc will be on the original question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [my identical question around 3 months ago:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep)

**Jeff Atwood:**

> The problem is that we don't know the user's chat reputation (except on SO and Meta.SO, because there it's identical to the main site rep).
>
> So for low-rep users, we'd have to ask the chat site via HTTP -- either when the warning is displayed for the first time, or at least remember that it failed when someone clicked.