# Remove chat notification when communicating to low rep users

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep)

So, I was helping out on a homework question today (nice guy that I am and all) and was having an extended discussion in the comments. I was given the notification to move the discussion to chat. However, I was given a "I'm sorry, I can't do that, Bringer128" message:

[image: Low Rep feature fail]

Can we get these two features linked so that the automatic move notification doesn't pop up given the low rep user?

EDIT: Oops, duplicate of [another question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep) I did search, honest!