# Comments recommend chat use, even if user doesn't have chat privileges

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep)

As a new user if you're answering questions and holding discussion with the OP via comments, then the popup appears recommending that you use chat instead of comments.  However if you're a new user, you click on it and it says you don't have chat privileges.