# Enable chat for users with insufficient rep when a discussion starts in comments

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invite low rep users to participate in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291/invite-low-rep-users-to-participate-in-chat)

This is closely related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep) but it is specifically a feature request. The 'new suggestion' in that post wasn't addressed and I think it is worth suggesting again.

I think that questions from new users who are not experienced programmers often lead to discussions in comments because they require pointers on lots of little things that don't relate directly to the original question.

I think it would make sense if there was an exception where if a discussion starts in the comments between a user with a rep and a new user then they should be allowed to move those comments to chat.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100291

Comment: Yeah thanks - I didn't spot that one, I've flagged as duplicate