# Please avoid discussion ... go to chat

Tags: discussion, reputation, chat, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep)

I'm helping a user here: [Purpose of BAL in 3 tier architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779574/purpose-of-bal-in-3-tier-architecture/11779643#11779643)

The guy keeps putting comments and he seems to need a little more help with his issue. 
Great I thought if I click on the textbox to "comment" again I'll get the cool notice:

> "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to
>   automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Finally, an easier way to help the guy so I click on the link (Its there isn't it so why shouldn't I click on it and help the guy).  It comes up and says Nope cant do the chat cause the guy doesn't have enough rep.

Call me what you want but these limitations and "teasers" on the UI are just not pleasant.  If the guy can't chat eliminate the ability to.  Or if you want happy end users, if I want to chat and further assist the guy eliminate the minimum reputation requirement in order to enable chat.  How is this fair to me or the user, I have my own work to do but I decided hey this guy needs a bit more help (we were all there once in our careers so why not help the guy - besides its the right thing to do and Joel talked about The Summer of Love).

How can I take advantage of "Chat" as one of the mods mentioned in the blog (specifically Robert Harvey) if we cannot use chat because of a minimum rep rule?

Comment: While I'm not sure this is a constructive question (comes off kind of rant-y to me), you might be interested in [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291/167443) (which this *may* be a duplicate of, if that is indeed what you are getting at).

Comment: Could be a duplicate of either. Not sure what this question is actually *asking* though (other than "how can we do this if it's not allowed?", which I guess both of those are potential answers to)