# Hide unavailable actions for underprivileged users (automatically move to chat)

Tags: feature-request, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep)

I'm currently trying to help somebody with his [bytecode instrumentations woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770353/java-asm-bytecode-modification-changing-method-bodies/11781125#11781125) and he keeps commenting below my answer. I'm new here, so my reputation is too low (1) to move the discussion to chat.

Because we exceeded some internal comment counter, SO suggests to automatically move the discussion to chat - which I would love to do, but I can't.

Could you please hide the taunting option or enable a "privilege override" in a scenario like this?

Btw: I'm unsure if this is a bug report or a feature request, so I'm using both in the tags.

Comment: I like the alternative: permit chatting in the room generated by migrate to chat. I think there was a broader question about temporary chat access for low rep users in the past somewhere.

Comment: It's already a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97876/167443)

Comment: I find it very hard to believe this keeps coming up; you need just 20 rep to use chat.

Comment: Related and [meta-tag:status-planned]: [Allow temporary guest accounts in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82738) and [Invite low rep users to participate in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100291)

Comment: Deja Vu I posted this yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142069/please-avoid-discussion-go-to-chat

Comment: True, it's a duplicate, my bad. Close it if you want to (I'd like to, but I can't yet).