# "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" unavailable if user haven't 6 reputation

Tags: bug

[image]

I get the advice to move the discussion to the chat, but one of the users in the discussion has no chat privileges yet. So I think it's a bug to advice a user without chat privileges to move the discussion to the chat area.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what the "bug" exactly is? Are you saying that the option should not be available?

Comment: @gamecat - The OP **does** have chat privileges, it's the other user that does not.

Comment: This has been asked dozens of times - example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142069/please-avoid-discussion-go-to-chat

Comment: I'd like to remind everyone that some assumptions were made with regard to the actual question/bug in this post. The current question is quite different from the [OP's version](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/149445/1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. Users can only use chat when they have 20 reputation points. This is part of the [Talk in chat privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/chat)

> Why do I need 20 rep to talk in chat?
>
> Your reputation on chat is the same as your reputation on the parent
>   site.
>
> You can always enter chat rooms and listen with no rep at all.
>
> We can't allow anonymous participation on chat, so we require a small
>   bit of parent site reputation to ensure that chat is reserved for
>   active, engaged members of the community.

With regard to why that suggestion appears at all when not all the participants are capable of using the chat rooms, I think the main idea that is trying to be conveyed is

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: Perhaps the suggestion to move the discussion to chat is the bug? :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even if it were, this has probably been asked many times here.

Comment: Sure, and thus it probably should be marked as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

After much thought:

Consider a person with less than 20 rep, having an extended discussion in comments.

If the discussion is about how SO is supposed to or does work, then the person is likely not understanding the other commenter and won't after a chat discussion.

If the discussion is not about how SO works, then `Please avoid extended discussions in comments` applies directly.