# Why move a discussion to chat even if an asker has not enough privileges?

Tags: discussion, bug, chat, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep)

There is a link with a proposal to move a discussion to chat.

It's a stackoverflow.com site where user reputation is known as I understand ([the source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep)).

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

But the author of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989742/django-using-a-raw-query-to-limit-a-foreignkey-choicefield-in-a-modelform) has not enough privileges to go to chat. Is this inaccuracy?

Comment: @Bart Almost, but not exactly a duplicate. The linked post also contains a feature request to give the low-rep user a field promotion.

Comment: @Bart As I understand it's not exactly a duplicate because it's stackoverflow.com where reputation is known. Thank you very much for the link.