# Long Comments moved to chat disabled unless user has high enough reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

I have seen this a few times, when helping **new users of SO**, and the comments can sometimes drag on longer than SO usually allows for.  After ~6 comments, SO prompts to '*Automatically move discussion to chat*', but if the user has **less than 20 reputation**, you are unable to do this.  Can the feature be **disabled** if the user is unable to enter chat?

Comment: See [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep).

Comment: If how often a feature gets suggested is considered a useful metric, this one should *definitely* be implemented.