# Stack Exchange site not redirecting us to chat after long series of comments?

Tags: support, comments, chat

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307579/job-posting-wont-delete-keep-getting-id-is-undefined) the Stack Exchange site Stack Overflow doesn't suggest the link to redirect us to the discussion although we had a long series of comments.

Should long series of comments always be redirected to chat on all Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other person in that conversation has a reputation of only 1... And as such, they can't chat. So the system won't offer to move the conversation, since that would essentially leave you chatting with yourself!

#### See also:

- [Stack Overflow should not invite you to move a discussion to chat when one of the participants doesn't have enough reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275771/stack-overflow-should-not-invite-you-to-move-a-discussion-to-chat-when-one-of-th/285690#285690)
- [Disable chat migration notification if one of the users has insufficient rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep/318314#318314)